# How to enable button on based dirty grid record

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a `save button` which I wanted to enable only when grid is dirty. I mean If I modified any row value in grid I want to be enable. Currently My button is disable.
My Button code is.

```
{
xtype : 'button',
text : "Save",
disabled: true,
handler : function () {
//Code
}
}
```

I don't have an idea how to make that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `grid dirty` is any property. You soluntion is something like this. Since you are using ExtJS 3 then You need to use id for button. and then take a store and check if any record is modified or not. if modified then make disabled false.

Sample code is :

First add id :

```
{
xtype : 'button',
text : "Save",
id : 'Save_Btn';
disabled: true,
handler : function () {
//Code
}
}
```

then use below code.

```
var SaveBtn = Ext.getCmp('Save_Btn');
var recordLength = gridStore.modified.length;
if(recordLength > 1)
    SaveBtn.setDisabled(false);
```

or you can use by selection :

Code is

```
var record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
var SaveBtn = Ext.getCmp('Save_Btn');
if(record.length > 0)
SaveBtn.setDisabled(false);
```